# DRF- how to return field which is not included in model in response

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, view, django-serializer

I have view:

```
class SomeView(APIView):
   def get(self,request):
   serializer = serializers.SomeViewSerializer
   return Response({'result_url': ???})
```

and serializer:

```
class SomeViewSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   def get_url(self):
      res_id = genetare_url(self.id)
      return res_id
```

in this case url is not part of any model, but I want to return only this (result of get_url) in response, but I couldn't figure out how to write it in view above. any help will be appriciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call the serializer's method.

```
class SomeView(APIView):
   def get(self, request):
       serializer = serializers.SomeViewSerializer()
       return Response({'result_url': serializer.get_url()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Add `obj` parameter into MethodFiled `get_url(self, obj)`

```py
class SomeViewSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   def get_url(self, obj):
      res_id = genetare_url(self.id)
      return res_id
```

and pass any data into serializer

ex: `SomeViewSerializer(request.data)` like this:

```py
class SomeView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = SomeViewSerializer(request.data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This might help you.

Comment: I got `Object of type property is not JSON serializable` error

Comment: I edited my answer and check it again. It should work now. `genetare_url(self.id)` here you may use `obj.id` if any.